# Can xbox360 and mobile cross play Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

My friend used an Xbox 360 for Minecraft and I use mobile but since were both bedrock (haters will say it’s not) I kinda thought we could play together:/

Comment: I think if you are on Xbox 360, you _aren't_ on Bedrock, but rather Legacy Console edition, which definitely cannot play with Bedrock users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possble to access Minecraft PE worlds on an xbox 360?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/244347/is-it-possble-to-access-minecraft-pe-worlds-on-an-xbox-360)

Answer (score 5):

You guys in fact, are *not* both on the Bedrock edition of Minecraft. Your friend is on the [minecraft-legacy-console](/questions/tagged/minecraft-legacy-console) edition of Minecraft, while you are on the [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition). You can see the difference by going on the main screens. Minecraft Legacy Console edition is discontinued, therefore you cannot play with your friend.

Answer (score 1):

A simple search for "Can Xbox and Mobile play Minecraft together" on the internet will tell you that Minecraft, indeed, is cross-platform.

All you need to do is invite a friend to your world by selecting the option "Find Cross-Platform Friends" and then enter their Minecraft ID to add them as a friend.

Please do more research before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Xbox 360 players can only play with other Xbox 360 players.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! If you want to reply to another answer use the comment section (and you'll be able to use that after gaining more reputation)

Comment: This answer is true if we are talking about the console edition (old version of Minecraft). If you bought it recently, it should support cross play.